# How to encode text with greek letters in a QR Code in android studio

Tags: java, android

So i'm trying to make a QR code that when scanned it returns a text.
Here's the code.

```
//GenerateCode is a button
GenerateCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = PlayerAddEditText.getText().toString(); //PlayerAddEditText is an editText
                try {
                    MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
                    BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(name, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200);
                    BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                    Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                    QRCodeImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //QRCodeImageView is an imageview
                } catch (WriterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Everything works fine with english letters but when i enter greek letters in the editText and run the code the result string returns question marks.
I try online QR generators to see if the problem is when i scan the QR code but it work fine with the online one's so i think the problem is my QR code generator code.But here's the code for getting the result(Scan QR Code).

```
//ScanCode is a button
ScanCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ScanCodeOnClick();
            }
        });
    }
    public void ScanCodeOnClick() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        ScanQRView.setResultHandler(AddPlayerActivity.this); // ScanQRView its a view that the camera is show(Instead of opening camera activity)
                        ScanQRView.startCamera();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        toastMake("Πρέπει να πατήσεται αποδοχή"); //Translation:You have to accept the Permission
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

                    }
                })
                .check();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        ScanQRView.stopCamera();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        QRPlayerValues = rawResult.getText(); //QRPlayerValues is the result string;
        PlayerAddEditText.setText(QRPlayerValues);
        ScanQRView.startCamera(); 
    }
    public void toastMake(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I'm using 2 phones to do that in the same application but i have a button to generate and a button to scan(Just for clarification).I need to be able to scan and get greek letters when the user input greek letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this for russian letters, it will work for your case too, i think. Set your charset in line `hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "Cp1251");`:

```
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.datamatrix.encoder.SymbolShapeHint;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

/**
 * Created by aprisadkov on 13.03.2019.
 */
public class QRCodeHelper {
        public static byte[] generateImage(String contents) throws WriterException, IOException {
            return generateImage(contents, 256);
        }

    public static byte[] generateImage(String contents, int size) throws WriterException, IOException {
        QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "Cp1251");
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.DATA_MATRIX_SHAPE, SymbolShapeHint.FORCE_RECTANGLE);

        BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(contents, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size, hints);
        ByteArrayOutputStream w = new ByteArrayOutputStream(size*size);
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", w);

        return w.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

upd:also you can use hints in line  `BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(name, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200);`

Comment: I think you saying to change "Cp1251" to greek language charset

Comment: Do you know what should i google to find this cause i only find results like U+0390 and this don't work

Comment: I found it you should replace "Cp1251" with "ISO-8859-7" at least this work for greek.

Comment: @FotisPozoglou this means trouble then you create String from byte[]. In this monent you can set charset roo